# Unable to Authorize with Uber. Duplicate redirect_uri parameter

Tags: uber-api

Since Friday, March 11 it is impossible to authorize with Uber.

Once user is prompted to Approve (Accept) Application permissions uber response with the following error (redirects to URL with following params):

```
callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=Duplicate+redirect_uri+parameter.
```

Although if Uber Account is already `connected` with Application user can successfully log in.

I'm using `nodejs`, `express`, `passport`, `UberStrategy`, which uses `passport-oauth2`. We've been using Uber API for last 5 months and never had this issue before and none of these libs were updated on our side.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: _“Since Friday, March 11 it is impossible to authorize with Uber”_ – if you can say that with that level of absolute certainty – then you should contact their developer support, and file a bug report if possible.

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately SO is the only way to communicate with Uber support – report a bug. Previously they were accepting emails with bugs, but last time I've submitted a bug/question I was asked to write it on StackOverflow. This time I sent an email and raised a question here at the same time.

Comment: I have just noticed the same problem with my app that has been successfully using the Uber API for months. I will been reporting the issue as well. You can contact support either at `uber-api-support@uber.com` or on twitter `@UberDevelopers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this! We rolled out a fix, it should be working now. Please let me us know if you still have any trouble.

Comment: Thanks Richard! I can confirm that oAuth works again as expected. Appreciate your help and fast response.